# Jquery autocomplete not showing the desired result

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-autocomplete

I've this code

```
 $("#tb1").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "../mycontroller/getdata",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { strText: "" },
                success: function (Data) {
                    response($.map(Data.Data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.Name,
                            value: item.Id
                        };
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 1,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            alert(ui.item ? "Selected: " + ui.item.label : "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
        }
    });
```

I get the result in textbox, however it shows all the items in list instead of showing seleted items.

**For example:-**
After i enter "ab" in textbox it should display all the items with ab but it shows items with ca, as and other alphabets combinations.

what am i doing wrong, how can i resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
data: { strText: "" }
```

to:

```
data: { strText: $("#tb1").val() }
```

you are not sending the textbox entered value so it is bringing all records.

Comment: thanks for the answer, do you have any idea abot this question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26103285/find-selected-item-in-datalist-in-html