# Find selected item in Datalist in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-datalist

I've a datalist something like this

```
<input list="browsers">

<datalist id="browsers">
  <option id="op1" value="Internet Explorer">
  <option id="op2" value="Firefox">
  <option id="op3" value="Chrome">
  <option id="op4" value="Opera">
  <option id="op5" value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

I'm adding "option" using jquery to datalist. Now the question is how can i find which option is selected/clicked by the user in datalist. I want to get the id of option as soon as it is is selected/clicked by user?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get selected value in datalist using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844373/get-selected-value-in-datalist-using-jquery)

Answer (score 9):

You can add an ID to the input field - and listen for the input event.  Then you have to get the value of the input to use in the selector to get the selected option

```js
$(function() {
  $('#browserinput').on('input',function() {
    var opt = $('option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]');
    alert(opt.length ? opt.attr('id') : 'NO OPTION');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='browserinput' list="browsers">

<datalist id="browsers">
  <option id="op1" value="Internet Explorer" />
  <option id="op2" value="Firefox" />
  <option id="op3" value="Chrome" />
  <option id="op4" value="Opera" />
  <option id="op5" value="Safari" />
</datalist>
```

Comment: what if i've same value for any 2 options.. theni'll always get the first option..

Comment: @SidM then you should probably use a select dropdown instead of a datalist because a datalist is used as an autocomplete for inputs

Comment: yeah i need that autocomplete functionality with dropdown, hence i was using data list

Comment: but there's no way to differentiate when there's 2 of the same value when using a datalist

Answer (score 3):

Try this way

```
<input list="browsers" id="input">

<datalist id="browsers">
  <option id="op1" value="Internet Explorer">
  <option id="op2" value="Firefox">
  <option id="op3" value="Chrome">
  <option id="op4" value="Opera">
  <option id="op5" value="Safari">
</datalist>

$(function(){
    $('#input').change(function(){
        console.log($("#browsers option[value='" + $('#input').val() + "']").attr('id'));
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/smap06ro/45/

Comment: can you create a fiddle for the same?

Answer (score 2):

Try this, I got the 'data-id' value.

```
<input list="browsers" id="input">
<datalist id="browsers">
 <option data-id="op1" value="Internet Explorer">
 <option data-id="op2" value="Firefox">
 <option data-id="op3" value="Chrome">
 <option data-id="op4" value="Opera">
 <option data-id="op5" value="Safari">
</datalist>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#input').change(function(){
        var abc = $("#browsers option[value='" + $('#input').val() + "']").attr('data-id');
        alert(abc);
    });
});
</script>

//if you click/choose 'Firefox' then 'op2' will show
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check that with is(':selected')

```
$('#browsers option').each(function() {
    if($(this).is(':selected')){
     // Your code here with the selected value
   }
});
```

Or to get the selected option value

```
 $('#browsers').val();
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle for the same?

Comment: Here you are http://jsfiddle.net/hLzbLhb4/1/ After selecting click anywhere to see the alert, so it would be something like focusout

Comment: Basically you need to check for the value of the input field, so if the input field has value show it etc.

Comment: thanks for the fiddle...however i want the value as soon as its changed(without clicking anywhere else)

Comment: What if the user inserts something that is not on the list?

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The `datalist` doesn't support the `:selected` pseudo-class, because a datalist can provide suggestions for multiple inputs and each can contain a different selection from the list. The fiddle in the comments does something entirely different.