# Get the selected option from datalist in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-datalist

Now i Know there are questions similar to mine. But in this case please if possible explain without using PHP... Just JavaScript!

In HTML, I have the following code :

```
<input id="citiesinput" list="cities">
<datalist id="cities"></datalist>
```

Since I can't change the HTML, I added the options with JavaScript :

```
 var list = document.getElementById("cities");
 var option = document.createElement("option");
 option.text = "New Delhi";
 list.appendChild(option);
```

Just imagine that there are more options in the datalist.
So in javaScript how do I select which option is the one selected by the user. because .selected doesn't work with dataList.

Also unlike the questions that you are posting. I can not use any other language than javascript. Also I can add no further attributes to the option tags. That is it. I am getting a list from a server for the names of the cities. I am putting them one by one into the datalist through a for loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find selected item in Datalist in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26103285/find-selected-item-in-datalist-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

You hava to post it to php.

Try this: http://codesheet.org/codesheet/wOHDXFju

```
onmousedown="javascript:postContent('1','New Delhi');"
```

the .js

```
function postContent(pid, pc) {
  $("#myDiv").html('L  O  A  D  I  N  G ...').show();
  var url = "/post.php";
  $.post(url, {id: pid, city: pc} ,function(data) {  //contentVar is the variable in post.php
       $("#myDiv").html(data).show();
    });
}
```

this is posting yout data to a in this case post.php into a div#myDiv

Comment: Thanks very much dude.

Answer (score 0):

okay. did some messing around with the code.

```
var selectedCity = document.getElementById("citiesinput");
```

the var selectedCity now holds the option that is selected in the datalist.
I am so disappointed in myself. but just in case someone else screws up.

In a datalist you do not need the .selected command.