# html data- attribute with option tag within datalist tag

Tags: javascript, html, html-datalist

Code:

```
<div style="display:table-row;">
    <div style="display:table-cell;" id="page-wrapper" >
    <label for="default_list">Search for GST : </label>
    <input type="text" id="default_list" list="widget_for" placeholder="Type to search ">

    <datalist id="widget_for" name="widget_for" style="overflow: scroll; width: 100%; height:500px" >
    {% for list in opt_list %}
        <option value="{{list.name}}" data-id="{{list.id}}" size="5" > </option>
    {% endfor %}        
    </datalist>    
    </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" class="button" id="save-node-type" value="Create" onclick="NavigateToSite()"/>
```

I want to fetch the data-id attribute when the option is selected.
The JS used is as follows:

```
function NavigateToSite(){
    var default_list = document.getElementById('default_list')
    var basic1 = default_list.getAttribute('data-id')
    console.log(basic1)
}
```

The o/p is null every time. where has it gone wrong?

Comment: your html element `default_list` does not have a `data-id`

Comment: @Dejan.S I want to obtain the data-id value of the option tag selected. So what corrections should be done ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find selected item in Datalist in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26103285/find-selected-item-in-datalist-in-html)