# HTML: Is it still not possible to select a data attribute from a datalist?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I've tried multiple approaches to get the selected item's data attributes (`data-id`, `data-key`), but nothing seems to work.

A couple of resources mentioned that this is not possible specifically for `datalist`...

**Is there a way to achieve this now, or is it still impossible?**

I'd really appreciate a vanilla Javascript way.

```js
document
  .getElementById('input-journal-item-company')
  .addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.dataset) // Empty object DOMStringMap {}
    console.log(e.target.dataset.id) // undefined
    console.log(e.target.getAttribute("data-id")) // null
  })
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input-journal-item-company" list="input-companies">
<datalist id="input-companies">
    <option data-id="1" data-key="001" value="Company 1">Company 1</option>
    <option data-id="2" data-key="002" value="Company 2">Company 2</option>
    <option data-id="3" data-key="003" value="Company 3">Company 3</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: `e.target` is the `datalist`, not the selected option.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26103285/find-selected-item-in-datalist-in-html for how to get the selected option.

Comment: The next time you post a question and claim something is impossible, please cite some source indicating where you saw it was impossible.  Generally we're happy to debunk things, but knowing the specifics can help us clear up any misconceptions you might have when we answer.  It's often the case that someone reads something and has the wrong interpretation of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.target` is the `input` value, not the `option` that the value came from. You need to search for the corresponding option.

```js
document
  .getElementById('input-journal-item-company')
  .addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    const option = document.querySelector(`#${e.target.list.id} option[value='${e.target.value}']`);
    console.log(option.dataset) // Empty object DOMStringMap {}
    console.log(option.dataset.id) // undefined
    console.log(option.getAttribute("data-id")) // null
  })
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input-journal-item-company" list="input-companies">
<datalist id="input-companies">
    <option data-id="1" data-key="001" value="Company 1">Company 1</option>
    <option data-id="2" data-key="002" value="Company 2">Company 2</option>
    <option data-id="3" data-key="003" value="Company 3">Company 3</option>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your JavaScript:

```
document
  .getElementById('input-journal-item-company')
  .addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    const listOption = e.target.list.querySelector('[value="' + e.target.value + '"]');
    console.log(listOption.dataset.id);
    console.log(listOption.dataset.key);
  })
```

The key here is that we use `e.target.list` to get the reference to the `<datalist>` element bound do the input element that's actually changing.  From there, we can query its children with `querySelector` for one that has a value which matches the input element's value.

http://jsfiddle.net/eboc9yzj/