# How pass data from ajax to Jquery UI autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have ajax code, it returns Json from Api, and i'm searching for a way, how can I pass this data to jquery autocomplete. 
Here is mo code:

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
      minLenght: 2,
      source: function(request,response) {        
      $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.myadres/search/"+$("#autocomplete").val(),
        crossDomain: true,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
         data: {
         "from" : "0",
         "take" : "10"
         },
        beforeSend: function() {  
          //alert ('working...');
        },      
        success: function( response) {
            for (i = 0; i < response.Results.length; i++) {
            // Console logs this data as desired, every time when i type something, console logging works good
            console.log(response.Results[i].Name);
            };          
          },
        error: function(  ) {
            alert( "Error occured!" );
        },   
        complete: function( xhr, status ) {
        }              
      })
     },
 });
```

I just have no idea how pass data from success callback to jquery autocomplete. Thank you for any advice.

Comment: See the question code how it is used.

this will help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26098188/jquery-autocomplete-not-showing-the-desired-result/26098263

Comment: The diffrence is, that link that you pass, is not my problem. My data is correctly. I just dont know how pass this data do autocomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`response` is a callback function that expect an array of string. You also declare a `response` value for your ajax, so you cannot access to the `response` function. You have to set an another name for your `success` parameter, like `ajaxResponse`. Make the array and call the `response` callback in your `success` ajax handler:

```
success: function(ajaxResponse) {
    var values = [];
    for (i = 0; i < ajaxResponse.Results.length; i++) {
        values.push(ajaxResponse.Results[i].Name);
    };
    response(values);
}
```

Comment: Now console show:
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
success: function( response) {
            var values = [];
            for (i = 0; i < response.Results.length; i++) {
            response(values);
            };          
          },

Comment: I change my answer, you had a variable name conflict.